# how to filter a set of data by variance in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have a set of data like this with a row for each minute in the last 4 hours:

```
[
{ X:1000, Y:2000, Z:3000, DateTime: 12/15/2018 12:00  },
{ X:998, Y:2011, Z:3020, DateTime: 12/15/2018 12:01  }
]
```

I need an array of property names whose values are within a 20% variance for all rows. So if Y and Z above meet this criteria but X does not then the output should look like this:

```
[Y, Z]
```

What typescript code could I use to do this?

Comment: Do all rows have the same properties?

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what "variance" or "variance percentage" mean in your question. I just used this formula to calculate variance: https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Variance
For the variance percentage, I simply divided the variance by the mean value and expressed it in percentage.
Feel free to replace my `calculateVariancePercentage` with a more correct implementation.

```js
const ACCEPTABLE_VARIANCE_THRESHOLD = 20;

const dataset = [
    { X:1000, Y:2000, Z:3000, DateTime: '12/15/2018 12:00'  },
    { X:998, Y:2011, Z:3020, DateTime: '12/15/2018 12:01'  }
];


const calculateVariancePercentage = (data) => {
    const meanValue = data.reduce((sum, element) => sum + element, 0) / data.length;
    const sumOfDeviations = data.reduce((sod, element) => Math.pow(element - meanValue, 2), 0);
    const variance = sumOfDeviations / (data.length - 1);
    return variance / meanValue * 100;
}

const variables = Object.keys(dataset[0]).filter(key => key !== 'DateTime');

const result = variables.filter(variable => {
    const varData = dataset.map(row => row[variable]);
    const varianceInPercentage = calculateVariancePercentage(varData);
    console.log(varianceInPercentage);
    return calculateVariancePercentage(varData) <= ACCEPTABLE_VARIANCE_THRESHOLD;
});

console.log(result);
```